# Contribution Receipt

Tags: civicontribute

The contribution receipt that is emailed to a donor has the person's first name such as:
Dear Albert,

Is there any way to have it also include the last name
such as:
Dear Albert Jones,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can change the default email greeting by navigating to Administer > Communications > Email Greetings - the system will use whatever format is marked as the default unless a different format is indicated in the [**Communication Preferences**](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/contacts/#communication-preferences-and-privacy-options) of contact's record.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: After configuring the new greeting, your current contacts' greetings will not be automatically updated. You can update everyone by using the 'update greeting' job in administer > system settings > scheduled jobs

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated but you can edit the system workflow message at Admin > Communications > Message templates, then go to the workflow tab and edit the appropriate Contributions - receipt. Find the line with Dear, then edit to replace the display name token with the first name and last name tokens. IIRC you need to change the Smarty by replacing each token separately, and use a special Smarty something to get rid of space if one of the names is empty. HTH